# MySQL: strange foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

I've got following two tables:

```
tree_instance:
  - tree_id INT
  - country_id INT
  - time_segment date

node_instance:
  - country_id INT
  - time_segment date
  - CONSTRAINT `node_instance_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`time_segment`) REFERENCES `tree_instance` (`time_segment`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Some facts:

- there are some nodes that exist in particular countries (nodes exist independently on countries)
- for each country there could be some trees that structure some of their nodes (within the same country)
- nodes don't have tree_id column, since they can be included in 0..n trees (there is another m:n table for that with tree_id column)
- nodes can be shared among different trees in the same country, but they can't be shared among different countries

---

When I add new structures, first I add new `tree_instance`, e.g.

```
tree_id: 2
country_id: 1
time_segment: 2014-01-01
```

Then I'm inserting nodes. And the same follows for country_id=2.

The problem occurs when I want to remove trees for one of the countries. First, I try to remove all node_instances for country_id=1. Success. Then I try to remove tree_instance WHERE country_id = 1 and I get following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`node_instance`, CONSTRAINT `node_instance_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`time_segment`) REFERENCES `tree_instance` (`time_segment`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

This is because there are node_instances from country_id=2 that point to time_segment that I want to remove (constraint). But the thing I can't understand is that there's still a tree_instance (country_id=1, which I don't remove) with a time_segment that can hold the constraint. Why is MySQL throwing constraint violation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is that MySQL non-unique constraint is MySQL-specific, as stated in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint that references a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL but rather an InnoDB extension.

The constraint on a non-unique index prevents deleting any matching rows. Any. No matter whether there is any other record that would still hold the constraint. The overall answer is that using constraints on non-unique fields is a bad idea, simply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the issue correctly, here's what you're trying to do

1. There's a foreign key in `node_instance` (child table) on `time_segment` column, referencing `tree_instance.time_segment`
2. You delete the records from `node_instance` (child table) for `country_id = 1`. This operation is successful
3. Now, you try to delete records from `tree_instance`, where you're getting error.

This is happening, since the foreign key is still present and active. It cannot let you delete parent records, as there might be records in child table, which are still referencing the record in the parent table. To delete a record in parent table, you need to disable the constraint.

EDIT:
I edited to refer to the correct foreign key columns. Even when the foregin key is on `time_segment` column, you will be able to delete records in child table, but you will not be able to delete records from parent table, since the foreign key from child table is referencing the `time_segment` column of the parent table. Delete is not allowed on parent table, since there might be some records in child table, which is referencing to a value of `time_segment` from parent table

Comment: point 1 is wrong, there's no `node_instance.country_id` -> `tree_instance.coutry_id`. There is `country` table with `id` column. The constraint is `node_instance.time_segment` -> `tree_instance.time_segment`

Comment: I have edited my answer. Even if the foreign key is on a different column, the parent-child relationship is still there, and so is the foreign key. You will not be able to delete records from parent table, just for the reason that one of the column has a referential integrity, and there might be a value in child table which is referencing it. Letting you delete the parent record, might result in orphan records

Answer (score 0):

Before the failing `DELETE FROM tree_instance WHERE country_id = 1` statement - check that `node_instance` does not contain rows with `country_id` = 1. If they are, then it is possible that previous modifications are not commited yet. So, check if existed transactions are commited; of course, if you use them.